# Google Application Engine Run cron job

Tags: google-app-engine

How I can set GAE cron job to run at specific date at specific time

Like 10th April at 12:20 minute.Please provide syntax for this use case.

How to set IST time zone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [cron format documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/cron#Java_appengine_web_xml_The_schedule_format):

> If you want more specific timing, you can specify the schedule as:
>
> `("every"|ordinal) (days) ["of" (monthspec)] (time)`
>
> Where:
>
> ordinal specifies a comma separated list of "1st", "first" and so
>   forth (both forms are ok) days specifies a comma separated list of
>   days of the week (for example, "mon", "tuesday", with both short and
>   long forms being accepted); "every day" is equivalent to "every
>   mon,tue,wed,thu,fri,sat,sun" monthspec specifies a comma separated
>   list of month names (for example, "jan", "march", "sep"). If omitted,
>   implies every month. You can also say "month" to mean every month, as
>   in "1,8,15,22 of month 09:00". time specifies the time of day, as
>   HH:MM in 24 hour time.

So you'd want something like:

```
schedule: 10 of april 12:20
timezone: Asia/Kolkata
```

Answer (score 1):

Possible solutions:

1) Create a cronjob that runs once a minute.  When the current time equals your desired time, run your code.

2) If the specific time is in the next 30 days, use a Task with the `eta` property set: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/tasks#Task

3) Use some external service to setup a webhook that gets called at the proper time, make your code run when the webhook is called.

Comment: IMO, option 1 is the most viable in this case.

Comment: @PeterKnego, yes it may... But it will also keep the targeted instance or frontend from being shutdown if there are no client requests made.